# Tag for Dell OS10 vs OS9

Tags: discussion, tags

Dell OS10 is very different from Dell OS9. Would it make sense to have different tags for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm. Currently, we've got two questions mentioning OS9, and three explicitly about OS10. I'm afraid that doesn't really warrant tags. There are 86 questions tagged [dell], could these potentially all be tagged either [os9] or [os10]?

Still, if you've got sufficient reputation (not sure how much, sorry) you can go ahead and add the tag to a question, creating the tag. Please make sure you also add some explanation to the tag wiki.

Comment: Create tags requires 300 points, not quite there yet. Thanks.